# How to prove that is a distance? equivalent distances?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

i have for $\Omega$ open we define $$f(x)=d(x,\partial\Omega)$$ and $$d'(x,y)=\sup\left(d(x,y),\left|\dfrac{1}{f(x)}-\dfrac{1}{f(y)}\right|\right)$$ where $d$ is a distance , how to prove that if $d'(x,y)=0\Rightarrow x=y$

If i suppose that $d'(x,y)=0$ then if $d'(x,y)=d(x,y)$ then  as $d$ is a distance we deduce that $x=y$ 
but if $d'(x,y)=\left|\dfrac{1}{f(x)}-\dfrac{1}{f(y)}\right|=0$ then how to deduce that $x=y$ please ?

I want also to prove that $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent over $\Omega$, we see that $d(x,y)\leq d'(x,y)$ what about the seconde inequality; $$\exists \beta >0, \forall x,y\in \Omega; d'(x,y)\leq \beta d(x,y)$$ thank you .

Comment: "distance" = "metric".

Comment: @AndréS. yes, please can you help me to prove the equivalence ?

Comment: There need not be such a $\beta$ I think.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma can we find a counter example ? please, i forget one thing we study the equivalence over $\Omega$

Comment: Pick points closer and closer to the boundary. Then $d'$ explodes.

Answer (score 2):

$d(x,y) \le d'(x,y) =0$. Now use $d$ is a metric. So $d'(x,y) =0$ implies $x=y$.

To show equivalence it suffices to show that if $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $\Omega$ under $d$ then the same holds under $d'$. (The inequality $d \le d'$ already gives us $x_n \rightarrow x$ under $d'$ implies that $x_n \rightarrow x$ under $d$))   This follows from continuity of $\frac{1}{f}$ (in the topology induced by $d$): $x_n \rightarrow x$ (under $d$) implies $d(x_n, x) \rightarrow 0$ and $\frac{1}{f(x_n)} \rightarrow \frac{1}{f(x)}$ and thus $|\frac{1}{f(x_n)} - \frac{1}{f(x)}| \rightarrow 0$ so $d'(x_n, x) \rightarrow 0$ and hence $x_n \rightarrow x$ under $d'$. So the topologies induced by these two metrics are the same as they have the same convergent sequences.

You cannot show that there is some $\beta>0$ such that $\forall x,x' \in \Omega: d'(x',x) \le \beta d(x,x')$. If $\Omega$ is a proper open set (say in the an Euclidean space), pick some $x \in \partial\Omega$ and a sequence $x_n \rightarrow x$ which means that $f(x_n) \rightarrow 0$. This implies that $|\frac{1}{f(x_n)} - \frac{1}{f(x_m)}| \rightarrow \infty$ as $ n,m \rightarrow \infty$, and the same thus holds for $d'(x_n, x_m)$. Note also that $x_n$ is $d-$Cauchy but not $d'-$Cauchy. It a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\Omega$ if $d'$-Cauchy it means that the $x_n$ "keep away" from $\partial \Omega$ and are contained in a proper closed subset of $\Omega$, and then $(x_n)$ is $d$-Cauchy as well.

Comment: i don't understand why you speak about Cauchy sequence, when we want to prove that two distances are not strong equivalent, we find a counter example we prove that $\forall \beta>0, \exists x,y\in \Omega, d'(x,y)> \beta d(x,y)$

Comment: @Vrouvrou because I want to show $(\Omega,d')$ is complete when $d$ is complete on $X$.

Comment: If metrics are strongly equivalent they have the same Cauchy sequences which is not the case here @Vrouvrou

Comment: i can't show like this because the last question is "prove that $(\Omega, d')$ is complete

Comment: also, we can't take x from $\partial\Omega$ we must take $x\in \Omega $because $\Omega$ is open

Comment: @Vrouvrou but the $x_n$ sequences *is* in $\Omega$ we just construct it using a point on its boundary.

Comment: but you find that the space is not complete but  in the book they proof that the space is complete

Comment: @Vrouvrou I said it *is* complete (read back) in the new metric, it's the whole point of its definition

Comment: the idea is that we choose $(x_n)\subset \Omega$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x\in \partial\Omega$ and we fixe $y\in \Omega$ then $f(x_n)\rightarrow 0$ so $d'(x_n,y)\rightarrow +\infty$ right ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou you start with a Cauchy sequence for $d'$, note that it is one for $d$ as well. So it has a limit in $X$

Comment: @Vrouvrou then show that this limit must lie in $\Omega$ and not on its boundary ( exterior is ruled out anyway ).

Comment: It is like to prove that the space $(E,d')$ is complete, but this question came after this question

Comment: I don't know why but i realy don't understand how to prove the not strong equivalence

Comment: please can you help me here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259292/topologicaly-equivalent-using-balls