# Topologicaly equivalent using balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We have two metrics, $d$ and $d'$ on an open set $\Omega$, such that $d'(x,y)=\sup\left(d(x,y),\left|\frac{1}{f(x)}-\frac{1}{f(y)}\right|\right)$ and $f(x)=d(x,\partial\Omega)$.

How can we prove that $d$ and $d'$ are topologically on $\Omega$ without using sequences?

If we take $y\in B_d'(x_0,r)$, then $d'(y,x_0)<r$, then $d(y,x_0)<r$: so $y\in B_{d}(x_0,r)$.

But if we take $y\in B(x_0,r)$, then $d(x_0,y)<r$. How do we find that $d'(x_0,y)<r$?

Comment: What is  $f(x)=d(x,\partial \Omega)$ ?

Comment: the distance between $x$ and $\partial\Omega$ @user198613

Comment: $\partial\Omega)$ is baundary of $\Omega$?

Comment: What's Omega?  What does d being toppogically on Omega mean?  Does it mean that d is a metric?  Apparently you want to show d and d' are topogically equivalent metrics for some set Omega.  Boundary of Omega needs to be explained or corrected to have f be defined.

Comment: @user198613 yes that is

Comment: @WilliamElliot $\Omega$ is an open set and $d$ is a metric on $\Omega$

Comment: Is this what you're asking?  Given an open set U of a metric space (S,d) is d'(x,y) = max (d (x,y), ans

Comment: @WilliamElliot no i mean the same open sets

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the equivalence of the two metrics $d$ and $d'$ on $\Omega$, you need to show two things:

$$\text{1. } \forall x \in \Omega: \forall r>0: \exists s>0 : B_{d}(x,s) \subseteq B_{d'}(x,r)$$

(Which shows that all $d'$-open sets are $d$-open) and

$$\text{2. } \forall x \in \Omega: \forall r>0: \exists s>0 : B_{d'}(x,s) \subseteq B_{d}(x,r)$$

(Which shows that all $d$-open sets are $d'$-open)

In this case, $d \le d'$ so 2. is trivial: we can take $s=r$,as you indicated.

For the other you have to use the continuity of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ on $\Omega$. Here you cannot use the same $s=r$, as you seem to think, though.

*Added upon request*: Let's take $(X,d)$ a metric space and let $h: (X,d) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ be a continuous function, where the latter set has the usual Euclidean metric $d_e(x,y) = |x-y|$. Then $d'(x,y) = \max(d(x,y), |h(x) - h(y)|)$ (no need for $\sup$ with two real numbers) is a metric on $X$ as well and $(x,d')$ is equivalent to $(X,d)$.

Proof: being a metric is easy. Clearly values of $d'$ are reals $\ge 0$ and $d'(x,y) = 0$ implies $d(x,y) =  0$ and as $d$ is a metric: $x=y$. Symmetry is clear as
$d'(x,y) = \max(d(x,y), |h(x) -h(y)|) = \max(d(y,x), |h(y) - h(x)|) = d'(y,x)$ using that $d$ and $|\cdot|$ are symmetric. For $ x,y,z$ in $X$ we have $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z)$ and $|h(x) - h(z)| = |h(x) - h(y) + h(y) - h(z)|  \le |h(x) - h(y)| + |h(y) - h(z)|$ as $d$ and the usual $|\cdot|$ metric on the reals are both metric, so the same inequality holds for their maxima ($a \le b, c \le d \rightarrow \max(a,c) \le \max(b,d)$ for any $a,b,c,d$ in a linearly ordered set), and so $d'$ obeys the triangle inequality as well.

The equivalence follows, because $d \le d'$ which again ensures that we can take $s=r$ in 2.

To see 1. we consider $x \in X$ and $r> 0$. Then continuity of $h$ gives us that there is some $\delta >0 $ such that for all $y \in X$ we have that $d(x,y) < \delta$ implies $|h(x) - h(y)| < r$. Now define $s = \min(r, \delta)$. Then If $y \in B_{d}(x,s)$ we know that $d(x,y) < s$. So in particular $d(x,y) < r$ and $d(x,y) < \delta$, so $|h(x) - h(y)| < r$ as well. It follows that $d'(x,y) = \max(d(x,y), |h(x) -h(y)|) < r$ as well (whichever of the two numbers is the actual maximum, it's always $< r$). So $y \in B_{d'}(x,r)$ as required: we have shown $B_d(x,s) \subseteq B_{d'}(x,r)$.

So the two metrics have the same open sets; they are equivalent. All of this applies to your case, where $h(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$ as well.

Comment: thank you but i have no idea on how to use continuity and when we same the same open sets we need the same center point and the same radius no ?

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou Added the argument. It isn't really hard if you look at it from a general angle.

Comment: @Vrouvrou you don't need the same radius for the same $x$. The $\forall r>0 \exist s>0$ condition two ways (1 and 2) are necessary and sufficient for the two metrics to be equivalent.